# Adding collision to maze walls

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection, maze

Can someone please help me adding collision points to my sprites. I had a past code where I layered a bitmap over images but the same code does not integrate well for physically drawing lines rather than detecting where the black/grey is on an image

```py
import random
import pygame
pygame.init()

WHITE = (255,255,255)
GREY = (20,20,20)
BLACK = (0,0,0)
PURPLE = (100,0,100)
RED = (255,0,0)

size = (701,701)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption("Maze Generator")

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

width = 25
cols = int(size[0] / width)
rows = int(size[1] / width)

stack = []

pos = (0,0)
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, pos, background):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(pos)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.pos)
        self.background = background

    def update(self, events, dt):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        move = pygame.Vector2((0, 0))
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]: move += (0, -1)
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: move += (-1, 0)
        if pressed[pygame.K_s]: move += (0, 1)
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]: move += (1, 0)
        #if move.length() > 0: move.normalise_ip()

        self.pos = self.pos + move*(dt/5)
        self.rect.center = self.pos        

        if self.background:

            new_rect.clamp_ip(self.background.get_rect())
            new_pos = new_rect.center

            hit_box = self.background.subsurface(new_rect)
            for x in range(new_rect.width):
                for y in range(new_rect.height):
                    if sum(hit_box.get_at((x, y))) < 500:
                        return

def load_background(filename=None):
    name = filename if filename else "background.jpg"
    background = pygame.image.load(name)
    background = pygame.transform.rotate(background, -90)
    background = pygame.transform.scale(background, (800,600))
    return background

def load_player(background):
    pimg = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
    pimg.fill((200, 20, 20))
    return Player(pimg, (25, 325), background)

class Cell():
    def __init__(self,x,y):
        global width
        self.x = x * width
        self.y = y * width

        self.visited = False
        self.current = False

        self.walls = [True,True,True,True] # top , right , bottom , left

        # neighbors
        self.neighbors = []

        self.top = 0
        self.right = 0
        self.bottom = 0
        self.left = 0

        self.next_cell = 0

    def draw(self):
        if self.current:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,RED,(self.x,self.y,width,width))
        elif self.visited:
            pygame.draw.rect(screen,WHITE,(self.x,self.y,width,width))

            if self.walls[0]:
                pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,(self.x,self.y),((self.x + width),self.y),1) # top
            if self.walls[1]:
                pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,((self.x + width),self.y),((self.x + width),(self.y + width)),1) # right
            if self.walls[2]:
                pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,((self.x + width),(self.y + width)),(self.x,(self.y + width)),1) # bottom
            if self.walls[3]:
                pygame.draw.line(screen,BLACK,(self.x,(self.y + width)),(self.x,self.y),1) # left

    def checkNeighbors(self):
        #print("Top; y: " + str(int(self.y / width)) + ", y - 1: " + str(int(self.y / width) - 1))
        if int(self.y / width) - 1 >= 0:
            self.top = grid[int(self.y / width) - 1][int(self.x / width)]
        #print("Right; x: " + str(int(self.x / width)) + ", x + 1: " + str(int(self.x / width) + 1))
        if int(self.x / width) + 1 <= cols - 1:
            self.right = grid[int(self.y / width)][int(self.x / width) + 1]
        #print("Bottom; y: " + str(int(self.y / width)) + ", y + 1: " + str(int(self.y / width) + 1))
        if int(self.y / width) + 1 <= rows - 1:
            self.bottom = grid[int(self.y / width) + 1][int(self.x / width)]
        #print("Left; x: " + str(int(self.x / width)) + ", x - 1: " + str(int(self.x / width) - 1))
        if int(self.x / width) - 1 >= 0:
            self.left = grid[int(self.y / width)][int(self.x / width) - 1]
        #print("--------------------")

        if self.top != 0:
            if self.top.visited == False:
                self.neighbors.append(self.top)
        if self.right != 0:
            if self.right.visited == False:
                self.neighbors.append(self.right)
        if self.bottom != 0:
            if self.bottom.visited == False:
                self.neighbors.append(self.bottom)
        if self.left != 0:
            if self.left.visited == False:
                self.neighbors.append(self.left)

        if len(self.neighbors) > 0:
            self.next_cell = self.neighbors[random.randrange(0,len(self.neighbors))]
            return self.next_cell
        else:
            return False

def removeWalls(current_cell,next_cell):
    x = int(current_cell.x / width) - int(next_cell.x / width)
    y = int(current_cell.y / width) - int(next_cell.y / width)
    if x == -1: # right of current
        current_cell.walls[1] = False
        next_cell.walls[3] = False
    elif x == 1: # left of current
        current_cell.walls[3] = False
        next_cell.walls[1] = False
    elif y == -1: # bottom of current
        current_cell.walls[2] = False
        next_cell.walls[0] = False
    elif y == 1: # top of current
        current_cell.walls[0] = False
        next_cell.walls[2] = False

grid = []

for y in range(rows):
    grid.append([])
    for x in range(cols):
        grid[y].append(Cell(x,y))

current_cell = grid[0][0]
next_cell = 0

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
def main():
    global current_cell

    player = None
    initialized = False
    current_maze = None
    dt = 0  
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    if not initialized:
        #current_maze = 0
        background = load_background()
        background = None
        player = load_player(background)
        sprites.add(player)
        initialized = True

    play = False 
    while not done:
        # --- Main event loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        for y in range(rows):
            for x in range(cols):
                grid[y][x].draw()

        if play == True:
            pygame.init()

            while not done:
                events = pygame.event.get()

                for e in events:
                    if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        return

                player_x = player.pos[0]
                player_y = player.pos[1]

                sprites.update(None, dt)

                #screen.fill(pygame.Color('grey'))
                #screen.blit(background, (0, 0))

                sprites.draw(screen)
                pygame.display.flip()
                dt = clock.tick(60)
        else:
            current_cell.visited = True
            current_cell.current = True

            next_cell = current_cell.checkNeighbors()
            if next_cell != False:
                current_cell.neighbors = []
                stack.append(current_cell)
                removeWalls(current_cell,next_cell)
                current_cell.current = False
                current_cell = next_cell
            elif len(stack) > 0:
                current_cell.current = False
                current_cell = stack.pop()
            else:
                play = True
        pygame.display.flip()


main()
pygame.quit()
```

I would love if anyone could help or point me in the right direction.

---

```
    end_rect = pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, (800-width, 600-width, width, width))
    if player.rect.colliderect(end_rect):
                    screen.fill(BLACK)
                    end = True
```

Comment: this is begging for an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I dont understand? The game runs fine its just collision that I dont understand how to ad

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where is the code for the collision detection?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Iv tried to intergrate collide_rect but tbh i didnt actually know what I was doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ensure that the `Player` object is positioned in the center of cell of the `grid`. e.g. calculate a random position for the `player`:

```py
def load_player(background):
    pimg = pygame.Surface((10, 10))
    pimg.fill((200, 20, 20))
    
    px = random.randint(0, rows-1) * width + width//2
    py = random.randint(0, cols-1) * width + width//2
    return Player(pimg, (px, py), background)
```

To track the player, but highlight the player position, the current player position has to be tint in a different color, before the player is updated and is redrawn:

```py
pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 164, 164), player.rect)
sprites.update(None, dt)
sprites.draw(screen)
```

For the collision test:

- The current position of the player in the `grid` has to be identified.
- The new possible new position of the player, dependent on the movement has to be identified.
- If a wall is on the track from the current to the new position, then the movement has to be skipped

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, image, pos, background):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = image
        self.pos = pygame.Vector2(pos)
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center=self.pos)
        self.background = background

    def update(self, events, dt):
        pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        move = pygame.Vector2((0, 0))

        # calculate maximum movement and current cell position  
        testdist = dt // 5 + 2
        cellx = self.rect.centerx // width
        celly = self.rect.centery // width
        minx = self.rect.left // width
        maxx = self.rect.right // width
        miny = self.rect.top // width
        maxy = self.rect.bottom // width
        
        # test move up
        if minx == maxx and pressed[pygame.K_w]:
            nexty = (self.rect.top-testdist) // width
            if celly == nexty or (nexty >= 0 and not grid[celly][cellx].walls[0]):
                move += (0, -1)

        # test move right
        elif miny == maxy and pressed[pygame.K_d]:
            nextx = (self.rect.right+testdist) // width
            if cellx == nextx or (nextx < cols and not grid[celly][cellx].walls[1]):
                move += (1, 0)
               
        # test move down
        elif minx == maxx and pressed[pygame.K_s]:
            nexty = (self.rect.bottom+testdist) // width
            if celly == nexty or (nexty < rows and not grid[celly][cellx].walls[2]):
                move += (0, 1)            

        # test move left
        elif miny == maxy and pressed[pygame.K_a]:
            nextx = (self.rect.left-testdist) // width
            if cellx == nextx or (nextx >= 0 and not grid[celly][cellx].walls[3]):
                move += (-1, 0)
        
        self.pos = self.pos + move*(dt/5)
        self.rect.center = self.pos
```

[image]

---

If you want to restart the maze, the you've to get rid of the nested game loops. Use 1 game loop and a condition, which state if the game is in `play` state or initializing the maze.

To check if the player has reached the goal can be done by [`pygame.Rect.colliderect()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect):

```py
finished = pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, width).colliderect(player.rect)
```

To restart you've to reset the `grid`:

```py
grid = []
for y in range(rows):
    grid.append([])
    for x in range(cols):
        grid[y].append(Cell(x,y))
current_cell = grid[0][0]
```

Set the player to a new random position:

```py
px = random.randint(0, rows-1) * width + width//2
py = random.randint(0, cols-1) * width + width//2
player.pos = pygame.Vector2(px, py)
player.rect = player.image.get_rect(center=player.pos)
```

Clear the background and reset the state `play`:

```py
screen.fill(0)
play = False
```

Full `main` code:

```py
def main():
    global current_cell, grid

    player = None
    initialized = False
    current_maze = None
    dt = 0  
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()

    if not initialized:
        #current_maze = 0
        background = load_background()
        background = None
        player = load_player(background)
        sprites.add(player)
        initialized = True

    play = False 
    while not done:
        # --- Main event loop
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                return

        if play == True:
            
            pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 164, 164), player.rect)
            sprites.update(None, dt)
            sprites.draw(screen)

            dt = clock.tick(60)

            finished = pygame.Rect(0, 0, width, width).colliderect(player.rect)
            if finished:
                # init new grid
                grid = []
                for y in range(rows):
                    grid.append([])
                    for x in range(cols):
                        grid[y].append(Cell(x,y))
                current_cell = grid[0][0]
                # create new random player positon
                px = random.randint(0, rows-1) * width + width//2
                py = random.randint(0, cols-1) * width + width//2
                player.pos = pygame.Vector2(px, py)
                player.rect = player.image.get_rect(center=player.pos)
                # clear screen
                screen.fill(0)
                play = False

        else:
            current_cell.visited = True
            current_cell.current = True

            next_cell = current_cell.checkNeighbors()
            if next_cell != False:
                current_cell.neighbors = []
                stack.append(current_cell)
                removeWalls(current_cell,next_cell)
                current_cell.current = False
                current_cell = next_cell
            elif len(stack) > 0:
                current_cell.current = False
                current_cell = stack.pop()
            else:
                play = True

            for y in range(rows):
                for x in range(cols):
                    grid[y][x].draw()

        pygame.display.flip()
```

see also [How do I prevent the player from moving through the walls in a maze?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68691507/how-do-i-prevent-the-player-from-moving-through-the-walls-in-a-maze/68691508#68691508)

Comment: youre a god. The clear maze code works great and im now working on my next goals for the game due to you :)